# Scheme member function, unsure of my definition

Tags: function, scheme

I want

```
(member? 'a '((d d) (d d)))
```

to return false

what am I doing wrong

```
(define (member? x list)
 (cond
  ((null? list) #t )
   (else ( or (or (eq? (car (car list)) x) (eq? (cdr (car list)) x)) (member? x (cdr list) ))  
)))
```

If someone can tell me what is wrong with my member function I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

((null? list) #t )

You're returning true if the list is empty. That's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it's a more general solution:

```
(define (member? ele lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((not (list? lst))
         (equal? ele lst))
        (else (or (member? ele (car lst))
                  (member? ele (cdr lst))))))
```

Notice that if you want to search inside a list of (arbitrarily nested) lists, the recursion is a little bit more elaborate: you have to consider the cases when the list is empty, when the list is not a list but a single element, and you have to recur on both the car and cdr parts of the list.

For example, the above definition will work for lists such as this:

```
(member? 'x '((a b) (c (x))))
> #t
```